# Dplyr - Time periods since first event

Tags: r, dplyr

Thanks in advance for your help. Assume I have this data frame.

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(tidyverse)
test <- tibble(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
               event=c("dog","cat","mouse","cat","mouse","dog"),
               quarter=(c(1,5,8,4,5,9)))
test
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      id event quarter
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1   dog       1
#> 2     1   cat       5
#> 3     1 mouse       8
#> 4     2   cat       4
#> 5     2 mouse       5
#> 6     2   dog       9
```

I would like to use `dplyr` to end up with the below data frame, such that for every given `id`, I know the number of `quarters` that have elapsed since the very first event.

```
test %>% cbind(quarterFrom = c(0,5,8,0,1,5)) %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id event quarter quarterFrom
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     1   dog       1           0
#> 2     1   cat       5           5
#> 3     1 mouse       8           8
#> 4     2   cat       4           0
#> 5     2 mouse       5           1
#> 6     2   dog       9           5
```

You can see that for `id == 1`, the first quarter is `1` and it receives `quarterFrom == 0`. However for `id == 2`, the first quarter is `4` and should also receive `quarterFrom == 0`. All other entries for a given `id` from then on out are the number of quarters that have elapsed since `quarterFrom == 0`.

Thanks again.

Comment: Your output is inconsistent.  For example, should row 2 be quarter=5, quarterFrom=4?

Comment: Hey - sorry about the counting confusion! Thanks [@Eric Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305688/eric-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize my counting is a bit different then yours, but that's simply because I don't follow your logic 100 %. Maybe you can clarify and I can update in response.

```
test %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(quarterFrom = quarter- first(quarter))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id  event quarter quarterFrom
#>   <dbl> <fctr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     1    dog       1           0
#> 2     1    cat       5           4
#> 3     1  mouse       8           7
#> 4     2    cat       4           0
#> 5     2  mouse       5           1
#> 6     2    dog       9           5
```

the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) website has [further illustrative examples of how to extract the first, last or nth value from a vector](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nth.html).

I just saw [thc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2723734/thc) posted a more or less identical solution. I think that answer is perfectly fine too - apparently he's – or she? – also confused by the counting.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example output has an off by one error in either id=1 or id=2.  If so, you can adjust by adding or subtracting 1 to this dplyr solution:

```
test %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(quarterFrom = quarter-min(quarter))

     id  event quarter quarterFrom
  <dbl> <fctr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1    dog       1           0
2     1    cat       5           4
3     1  mouse       8           7
4     2    cat       4           0
5     2  mouse       5           1
6     2    dog       9           5
```